# How to make Object property of a C# class optional?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable, non-nullable

I am trying to make a model class in C# in which i require object/List properties as optional property:

```
public class Customer
{
        [JsonProperty("Custid")]
        public string CustId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("CustName")]
        public string CustName { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Store
{
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Customer")]
        public List<Customer>? Customers{ get; set; }            *//Error 1*
        [JsonProperty("OtherProperty")]
        public object? OtherProperty{ get; set; }                *//Error 2*
}
```

The above code is giving error as :-
*Error 1:   The type 'object' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'

Error 2:    The type 'List' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'*

Please Explain me the above scenario and provide me with the alternate solution.

Comment: Have you tried Nullable<Type>?

Comment: Which c# version are you using?

Comment: It sounds like you basically need to: 1) make sure you're working with a C# 8 compiler; 2) make sure you've got it set to the right language version; 3) enable nullable reference types.

Comment: @JamalSalman C# 7

Comment: @fstam Nullable<Type> is not working for object type

Comment: @triptisinha what json parser are you using? I'm unfamiliar with anything other than newtonsoft so I can't test your code..

Comment: No, `Nullable<Type>` definitely wouldn't work. And if you're using C# 7, then you won't have nullable reference types either. So you probably just want `string`, `List<Customer>` and `object` as the property types.

Answer (score 10):

`string`, `List` and `object` are all reference types. Those are nullable by default. The `Nullable` type (e.g. `int?` is a shorthand for `Nullable<int>`) is only used for value types.

In C# 8.0, a new feature was introduced that allows for *non*-nullable reference types - i.e. reference types that explicitly disallow null assignment. This is an opt-in feature - you can enable it to allow you to more clearly show intent about the references. If you use this, the syntax used to define *nullable* reference types is the same as for nullable value types:

```
string nonNullableString = null; // Error
string? nullableString = null;   // Ok
```

Keep in mind that enabling non-nullable reference types means that all of the reference types that aren't followed by `?` will be non-nullable; this might require you to make lots of changes in your application.

So there's your two choices. Either enable non-nullable reference types, and then you need to explicitly mark types that you want to have nullable, or stick with nullable reference types, and just use `string` instead of `string?` for the same result. I would encourage the use of non-nullable types by default, since it holds some promise for avoiding an entire class of very common programming mistakes.

Comment: Except in the case of nullable reference types ;-)

Comment: @Magnus Or rather, if you enable non-nullable reference types :P

Comment: Nullable reference types were introduced in C# 8.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using `C# 8`:

`object?` doesn't exists. `object` is already nullable.

`List<Customer>?` doesn't exists. `List<Customer>` is already nullable.

If you want to use `nullable reference types` you must update your compiler version!

Comment: Nullable reference types were introduced in C# 8.

Comment: Yes, quite possibly - but your answer doesn't even consider the possibility that they're *trying* to use nullable reference types, and just are using the wrong compiler version. `object?` *does* exist, but only in C# 8 with nullable reference types enabled.

Comment: To put it another way: if someone had tried to write `public class Foo<T>` and got an error because they were using a C# 1 compiler, would you tell them that that's invalid syntax, or that they needed to use a newer C# compiler?

Answer (score 0):

The `Nullable<T>` type requires that T is a non-nullable value type, for example `int` or `DateTime`. Reference types like `string` or `List` can already be null. There would be no point in allowing things like `Nullable<List<T>>` so it is disallowed.

Comment: Nullable reference types were introduced in C# 8. Note that `string?` is *not* equivalent to `Nullable<string>` here - it's the same *syntax* as for nullable value types, but an entirely different approach.